# generating page title with razor script - umbraco

Tags: razor, umbraco, page-title

So I am trying to create a script whereby depending on the document type of the page a certain pre-defined title tag format will appear, if there is nothing already written in an overwriting custom title input. I have inserted the macro within the `title` tag on my master template but keep on getting an Error loading Razor Script message .

Html

```
<title>
    <umbraco:Macro Alias="NewPageTitle" runat="server"></umbraco:Macro>
</title>
```

Script -

```
@inherits umbraco.MacroEngines.DynamicNodeContext
@using umbraco.MacroEngines

    @{
      if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(@Model.tabName.ToString()) == false )
        {
          @Model.tabName
        }

      else if(@Model.DescendantsOrSelf("Country"))
        {
          <text>
            Holidays in @Model.Name
          </text>
        }

      else 
        {
          @Model.Name;
        }
    }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code out.  The problem with your original code is that you were using *"@Model.DescendantsOrSelf("Country")"* as a boolean, and it is a list.  I also removed your comparison for *if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(@Model.tabName.ToString()))*.

Also, if you add *?umbDebugShowTrace=true* to the end of your URL, you can get some valuable debugging information.  There is a Chrome Extension called "Umbraco Debug" that I use to quickly access that query string and information.  You may find it useful.

```
@inherits umbraco.MacroEngines.DynamicNodeContext
@using umbraco.MacroEngines

    @{
      if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(@Model.tabName.ToString()))
        {
          @Model.tabName
        }

      else if(@Model.DescendantsOrSelf("Country").Count() > 0)
        {
          <text>
            Holidays in @Model.Name
          </text>
        }

      else 
        {
          @Model.Name;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Hideous! I hadn't thought of it like that and works fine now, much appreciated. D

Comment: @Dante - I am glad I could help.  I am still learning this stuff so any help I can provide helps me as well. If you have a chance, mark this as the answer so it can update and I can get some "cred" LOL! Good luck!  =)

Answer (score 0):

its very simple just add following code into your title tag

```
@Umbraco.Field("pageName")
```

will display pageName,you may also add custom properties from document type.
e.g. you have added new property like "metaKeywords" with value "html,javascript,xml",fetch that values as following way...

```
@Umbraco.Field("metaKeywords")
```

even you don't need to add custom properties in your model